# Android: GPS not logging 90% of the time

Tags: android, gps

I'm using the following code on some Android devices. Very frequently (90% of the time) i don't get any gps updates within 75s.

Do you have any suggestions to the problem?

```
public class GPSLogger extends AbstractLoggerComponent {

    private static GPSLogger singleton = new GPSLogger();

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    private Context context;

    /**
     * GPSLogger.
     */
    private GPSLogger() { 

    }

    /**
     * @return singleton instance
     */
    public static GPSLogger getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void initialise(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        this.locationListener = new GPSLocationListener(); 
        super.initialise(context);
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected void start() {
        new Thread((new Runnable() {
            /** {@inheritDoc} */
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); 
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);
                Looper.loop();
            }
        })).start();
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected void stop()
    {
        this.locationManager.removeUpdates(this.locationListener);
    }

    /**
     * GPSLocationListener.
     *
     * The custom GPSLocationListener
     */
    private class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {           
            GPSSample gpsSample = new GPSSample();
            gpsSample.setAccurracy(location.getAccuracy());
            gpsSample.setBearing(location.getBearing());
            gpsSample.setLatitude(location.getLatitude());
            gpsSample.setLongitude(location.getLongitude());
            gpsSample.setSpeed(location.getSpeed());
            gpsSample.setTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            gpsSample.setAltitude(location.getAltitude());
            gpsSample.setProvider(location.getProvider());

            singleton.setChanged();
            singleton.notifyObservers(gpsSample);
        }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) { }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) { }

        /** {@inheritDoc} */
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) { }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    protected String getName() {
        return "GPSLogger";
    }
}
```

Comment: go outside for a better signal is the sarky answer. The correct answer is use the DDMS to mock your location and see if that is your problem

Comment: Why do you loop on `requestLocationUpdates`?

Comment: What OS version is your device?

Comment: I had to loop as Android required me to prepare a Looper or a handler. My OS is 4.1.2.

Comment: try to reduce "10000" to "1000" in location update request.

Comment: I've tried that and i've also tried to reduce the criterias (by using Androids Criteria object). But that didn't help. The I measured the GPS Signal and to my surprise it was very weak in the train and car...